# Mojave install failure "OSIInstallElement failed, Failure Reason: PKInstallErrorDomain:112"

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, install, external-disk

I'm trying to install Mojave on a brand new 2TB Western Digital external hard drive.  I've formatted the drive as APFS.  The installer gets partway through, and then fails with

> macOS could not be installed on your computer
>   An error occurred while running scripts from the package "Core.pkg".
>   Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.

Looking in /var/log/install.log, the relevant lines appear to be:

> 2019-07-25 06:25:26-07 JoeMBPro installerdiagwatcher[231]: ------- Install Failed -------
>   2019-07-25 06:25:26-07 JoeMBPro installerdiagwatcher[231]: Operation: OSIInstallElement failed, Failure Reason: PKInstallErrorDomain:112
>   2019-07-25 06:25:26-07 JoeMBPro installerdiagwatcher[231]: This was an attempted clean install from Unknown to 18G84

Those lines appear five minutes after the previous log entry, which looks like an ordinary progress update (setting window alpha values to 0).  So I think that's all the detail we get.

Any idea what's going wrong here?  I've spent a day and a half dealing with one failure after another on this process, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: This might have changed as Mojave has progressed, but I always thought you had to start with an HFS+ drive & let Mojave do the conversion. I'm trying to find a specific ref... I'd also double-check it's formatted GUID not MBR

Comment: Letting it convert to APFS was one of my earlier attempts.  It failed on the conversion.  When I did it with Disk Utility, then the installer seemed to get farther.  (And yes, it's formatted GUID; that was another earlier failure!)

Comment: Are you running this from the full downloaded App Store 10.14.6? I'm wondering if setting up a USB boot key with createinstallmedia might help... but tbh I'm just guessing now